# Adding a string from UserDefaults into an already made array Swift 3

Tags: arrays, swift, nsuserdefaults

I've got my users first name and I've set it in a UserDefault and I call it like so..

```
let firstName = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "firstName")
```

Then I have an array of strings and I would like to add the users first name into that..

```
var arrayOfTitle = ["HEY", "FIND EVENTS CLOSE TO YOU", "BOOK"]
```

I've tried what I would think it should look like which is

```
var arrayOfTitle = ["HEY \(firstName)", "FIND EVENTS CLOSE TO YOU", "BOOK"]
```

but that isn't working.

Would anyone be able to push me or demonstrate to get me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Comment: What does it say when it's not working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## UserDefaults.string(forKey:)

Use [`UserDefaults.string(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1416700-string) instead of [`UserDefaults.object(forKey:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/userdefaults/1410095-object).

```
let firstName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "firstName") ?? "YOU"
var arrayOfTitle = ["HEY \(firstName)", "FIND EVENTS CLOSE TO YOU", "BOOK"]
```

`UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey:)` returns `Any?` which you must unwrap and convert to a string. `UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:)` converts the result to `String?` which can simplify your code.

The nil-coalescing operator, `??`, unwraps the `String?` result if it contains a value, or returns the default value "YOU" if the result is `nil`. Without the `??` operator, if there is not a UserDefault stored for "firstName", it will return `nil` resulting in "HEY nil".

### Optional Binding

You can use optional binding with `UserDefaults.string(forKey:)` if you want to conditionally run code if a value exists or not.

```
if let firstName = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "firstName") {
    print("\(firstName)")
}
```

Comment: That worked perfect! - I also had to move everything into the viewdidload for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let name = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "firstName") as? String{
    arrayOfTitle.append(name)
}
```